# How to use separate database for testing in Laravel 5?

Tags: postgresql, laravel-5, phpunit

I need to run tests with a separate database

I use POSTGRESQL as database driver.

My config/database.php

```
'pgsql' => [
        'driver' => 'pgsql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
        'schema' => 'public',
        'sslmode' => 'prefer',
    ],
```

Special for running tests I defined `DB_DATABASE` in phpunit.xml

```
<php>
    <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
    <env name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
    <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
    <env name="MAIL_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <env name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false"/>
    ...
    <env name="DB_DATABASE" value="database_test"/>
</php>
```

But when I run my PHPUnit tests, I get the error

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL: database "database_test" does not exist

Comment: I would recommend following @thisiskelvin's approach below. However, if still want to use your approach, you just need to create the `database_test` database in postgres before running the tests.

Answer (score 2):

The new connection must be set within `database.php`.

I would recommend setting up a **sqlite** database connection specifically for testing:

```
...

'connections' => [
    'database_test' => [
        'driver'   => 'sqlite',
        'database' => ':memory:',
        'prefix'   => '',
    ],
...
```

This will create a sqlite database connection which runs in memory.

You must then set the `DB_CONNECTION` rather than the `DB_DATABASE`.

```
<env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="database_test"/>
```